# history.push doesn't show the destination path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

This seems like a simple task, but can't seem to get it to work. I'm building a React SPA running Material UI and Typescript. Due to errors, when I'm using Material UI Tables, and I have a Cell that's a link, then I have to use

`onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/link')}`

This creates a problem that the destination path is not being displayed in the bottom left corner (Chrome, also can't remember what this is called, but hope that someone understands what I'm referring to).

I've done a few searches, but can't seem to find anything relating to this.

Comment: Consider using `<Link>` instead of manually assigning to `onClick`. It handles these types of things properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [Link from react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) directly?
For instance:

```
<Link to="/link">Some Page</Link>
```

Comment: Used to use this, but want the whole TableCell to be clickable, and when I add the Link around the TableCell I get the error that <a> cannot be a child of <tr>

Comment: Then why not use <td> with 0 padding on tr. And then add Link to td.

Comment: That partially works, since i'm using Material UI, then the table cell width varies. Do you know how to get the link to cover the whole cell, as removing the padding doesn't seem to make the link cover the cell.